# How to Fit Perfect Squares Into a Rectangle

Tags: area

I have been looking all over the Internet for an answer on this. None of them answer my question, and I need help. The ones that do somewhat answer my question assume the fact I understand their college-level mathematical understanding, when in reality I am a 10th grade programmer.

I'm trying to make an emulated screen of a much lower pixel density, but can't seem to figure out how to figure out how many 50x50 squares my rectangular screen with a ratio of 3x4.

I appreciate all answers in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your screen is $1200 \times 900$ "normal" pixels, which is a $4:3$ ratio.

You can fit $1200/50 = 24$ giant pixels along the long edge, and $900/50 = 18$ giant pixels along the short edge.

So the total number of giant pixels is $24 \times 18 = 432$.

Another way is to use the area directly.  A $1200 \times 900$ screen has $108000$ pixels.  Each giant pixel contains $50 \times 50 = 2500$ normal pixels.  So in total you have $108000/2500 = 432$ giant pixels.

Is that what you're after?

Comment: +1. The only issue that could arise is if a whole number of giant pixels could not fit into one or more dimensions.

Comment: Thank you. After a while I figured it out. Looking back, that was a stupid question... thanks for your answer though!